Which text-to-image service/model can preserve character consistency?
Question from holydragon: which text-to-image service/model can preserve character consistency, i.e. can generated images that contain the same person that it is previously generated but now in a new image and can even have other poses?

Leonardo.Ai introduced the Consistent Characters feature in May 2024, which allows to define a Character Reference and a Character Reference strength.
Examples from their blog post:






